# AsyncApexJob record when I use System.scheduleBatch() method

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job, asyncapexjob

I have just found a very strange behavior regarding Batch.

If I have a Batch and run it using the method `Database.executeBatch()`, a new record inside `AsyncApexJob` table is created and I can use `ApexClassId` field to find it using my class name.

For the `Schedulable` I have the same behavior regarding `AsyncApexJob` table and I have a new record inside the `CronTrigger` table.

Instead, if I have a Batch and I decide to schedule it using the method `System.scheduleBatch()` I receive a new record only inside `CronTrigger` and nothing inside `AsyncApexJob`!

In this case, I am not able to find if a specific Batch is "scheduled" or not because using the record inside `CronTrigger` table I am not able to retrieve info about that class.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get class details for scheduled Apex jobs, as you say. What you can do is get the name of the scheduled job, which you can use to persist details your code can look for.

```
SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name = 'MY_JOB_STANDARD_NAME'
```

should do the trick.

When you schedule the batch, just pass some standard string to `System.scheduleBatch()` as its second parameter.

```
System.scheduleBatch(myBatch, 'MY_JOB_STANDARD_NAME', 200);
```

Then your code can always know whether or not its job is currently scheduled. You could even use your Apex Class Id as the job name, if you desire.